# How can I convert a pre-existing tensor to another data type in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensor, tensorflow.js

I'm using Tensorflow.js, and I want to convert a *pre-existing* tensor to another data type. For example, I might have an `int32` tensor I want to convert to a `float32` tensor.

It is documented that one can set the type of a tensor upon creation like so:

```js
let a = tf.tensor([1,2,3], null, "int32");
```

....but I have not been able to locate an API call [in the documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tensor) that operates on a pre-existing tensor.

Answer (score 0):

It is buried in the API documentation, but such a method does exist. You can convert a Tensor from one type to another like so:

```js
let example_tensor = tf.tensor([1,2,3]); // dtype is currently "float32"

example_tensor.cast("int32"); // now the dtype is "int32"
example_tensor.cast("bool"); // now the btype is "bool"
```

Link to API documentation: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#cast.

For reference, as far as I'm aware the following dtypes (short for "data type") exist:

- 'float32'
- 'int32'
- 'bool'
- 'complex64'
- 'string'

([source](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.reLU))